# IO: Error #2038 jquery uploadify firefox latest

Tags: jquery, firefox, uploadify

I'm using script which is uploading files to server via flash component. Sometimes, very rarely, when trying to upload images via Firefox Latest version (24.0) I get following error: IO error #2038.

The code is working on one local host but isn't on the other host, But for other browser(Chrome, IE and Safari, firefox pre-version 24.0) its working very fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your Flash player Plugin for latest version.
Using: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

If its not latest install latest version and see if your problem still exist.